# Can I use Picasa (or any other desktop client) to manage Picasaweb or Google+ albums?

Tags: google-plus-photos

I use Picasa to manage my offline photos.  I know that I can easily upload albums and pictures to Picasa or Google+.  Is there any way to use Picasa (or any other desktop app) to manage the pictures that are already online?

Comment: I'm not being funny - but why do you want to use a desktop app, not a web-app, to manage photos that are stored on-line?    What's wrong with just using teh web-app?

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ: Sorting pictures into folders on the website is very frustrating.  You can't drag and drop as easily as you can on the desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

1. If you don't have your online photos/albums in Picasa, download them.
2. Sync your changes on Picasa with Picasa Web Albums.

## How to. Part 1. Alternative 1: Import albums from Google Photos

Picasa version 3.9.140 for Windows offer a `Import from Google Photos` command. Picasa Web Albums are seen in Google Photos.

[image: Picasa - File menu]

### Part 1. Alternative 2: Download albums to your computer

From [Download, email, and move photos and albums - Picasa Help](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/39513?hl=en)

> ### Picasa Web Albums
>
> Download photos and albums
>
> #### Photos
>
> 1. Open the photo to download.
> 2. Click Actions > Download photo.
> 3. In the window that appears, select Save File.
>
> #### Albums
>
> 1. Open the album to download.
> 2. Click Actions > Download to Picasa.
> 3. In the window that appears, click "Download."

## How to. Part 2. From [Do more with Picasa & Picasa Web Albums - Picasa Help](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/66969?hl=en)

> ### Picasa
>
> #### Sync your changes
>
> Turn on Web Sync in Picasa to sync any changes to Web Albums.
>
> - On the right of an album, turn on the "Sync to Web"
>   switch.
> - Click the arrow next to the "Upload" button. Select Enable
>   Sync.

Comment: This is only a one-way sync from the computer to the web.  It doesn't let me manage the pictures that are already on the web.

Comment: @NathanFellman: You didn't say in your question that the online albums are not in your PC :)

Comment: I thought that was implied by the fact that I was asking about picasa**web** :-)

Comment: @NathanFellman: I updated my answer.

Comment: So will this keep the copies on the computer and on the web in sync, like with dropbox or google drive?

Comment: @NathanFellman that will keep the computer and web albums in sync, not exactly as Dropbox and Drive but in similar way. The difference is that Picasa creates a library (links) to the original location of local photos files while Drive require that the files are in the Google Drive folder.